# Can I use (via wifi only) my original VZW Droid without a voice or data plan?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, verizon, data-plan, activation

I have a situation similar to [Can I use an Android phone without an Internet access plan?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3897/can-i-use-an-android-phone-without-an-internet-access-plan) but with one key difference, I don't even want to use it as a phone. Just a PDA.

I have an original VZW droid, the phone powers up and I can start apps etc; however, I cannot even connect to WiFi (it tries and fails with an error that just says unable to connect, try again). Is this a limitation of the phone being ***not*** activated? I used to use this phone as my every day driver, but I've since upgraded to a new phone, but would still like to use this droid as a wifi web browser around the house.

Comment: Don't know why it would prevent you from being on Wi-Fi. Try putting it in Airplane mode then turning on Wi-Fi and connecting again?

Comment: @jlehenbauer Thanks. That sounds like a good test. I'll try that and report back.

Comment: stock motorola's usually want you to log into motoblur but apart from that it should just work

Comment: @ce4: The original Droid did not have Motoblur.

Comment: I use my Droid for wifi-based apps without any problem.   It's been off contract since last October.   Perhaps try a battery-out power off; if that doesn't work, try to forget your Wifi network and then re-add it.

Comment: Does your droid use a sim card? If nothing else works, try pulling the sim and see if that has any effect.

Comment: @MichaelKohne: VZW og Droids don't have SIMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, there shouldn't be any problem for using your phone as PDA only.

Answer (score 3):

There shouldn't be any problems using WiFi without having an active account on your og Droid.  There's a pretty good discussion of this same question on the thread ["repurpose old android phone"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12492/reusing-old-android-phone/22591#22591).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my HTC Hero. Even though I could toggle Wifi on and off while in Airplane mode, it would fail to connect. Turning Airplane mode off solved the problem.